# how to change onclick event with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have create a js file in which i am creating the dynamic table and dynamically changing the click event for the calendar but onclicking the calender image for dynamic generated table, calendar popup in the previous calendar image.
Please help me

code

```
/***------------------------------------------------------------
* 
*Developer: Vipin Sharma
* 
*Creation Date: 20/12/2010 (dd/mm/yyyy)
* 
*ModifiedDate   ModifiedBy      Comments (As and when)
* 
*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
var ia = 1;
jq(document).ready(function(){
    jq("#subtaskid1").click(function() {
        if(ia<=10){
      var create_table = jq("#orgtable").clone();
      create_table.find("input").each(function() {
        jq(this).attr({
          'id': function(_, id) { return ia + id },
          'name': function(_, name) { return ia + name },
          'value': ''               
        });
      }).end();
      create_table.find("select").each(function(){
            jq(this).attr({
                'name': function(_,name){ return ia + name }
            });
      }).end();
      create_table.find("textarea").each(function(){
            jq(this).attr({
                'name': function(_,name){ return ia + name }
            });
      }).end();
      create_table.find("#f_trigger_c").each(function(){
            var oclk = " displayCalendar(document.prjectFrm['"+ ia +"dtSubDate'],'yyyy-mm-dd', this)";                          //ERROR IS HERE
            var newclick = new Function(oclk);
            jq(this).click(newclick);
      }).end();
      create_table.appendTo("#subtbl");
      jq('#maxval').val(ia);
      ia++;
        }else{
            var ai = ia-1;
            alert('Only ' + ai + ' SubTask can be insert');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try the jQUery UI Datepicker. It works really well for me. http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 229, accepted):

You can easily change the `onclick` event of an element with jQuery without running the new function with:

```
$("#id").attr("onclick","new_function_name()");
```

By writing this line you actually change the `onclick` attribute of `#id`.

You can also use:

`document.getElementById("id").attribute("onclick","new_function_name()");`

Comment: Just for information, if you have some parameter to pass to your `new_function_name`, you can write :  
`$("#id").attr("onclick","new_function_name('"+param1+"', '"+param2+"')");`  
This is what I was looking for when I found this answer, and it helped me. +1
`

Answer (score 42):

Remove the old event handler

```
$('#id').off('click');
```

And attach the new one

```
$('#id').click(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 19):

Updating this post (2015) : unbind/bind should not be used anymore with jQuery 1.7+. Use instead the function off().
Example :

```
$('#id').off('click');
$('#id').click(function(){
    myNewFunction();
    //Other code etc.
});
```

Be sure that you call a non-parameter function in .click, otherwise it will be ignored.

Comment: With jQuery, you could reduce the amount of code with this: `$('#id').off('click').on("click", function() { ... });`

Comment: @NuclearPeon you're reducing it by a semicolon and a newline lol, making it harder to read

Comment: @quemeful Not necessarily. You could put the `on` and `off` click events on their own indented lines to make it more readable (comments make it hard to show), but my version does more than change the look of the statement. Whenever you call `$(...)`, it does a lookup for that element. Writing `$("#id")` twice will lookup the element in DOM twice, meaning my version is twice as efficient. With id lookups, it's a minimal improvement, but with class/element/property/data lookups, it adds up. To make it work as efficiently as mine, put `$("#id")` in a `var` and work off that.

Answer (score 6):

`$('#id').attr('onclick', 'function()');`

Right now (11 Jul 2015) this solution is still working (jquery 2.1.4); in my opinion, it is the best one to pick up.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change one specific onclick event with jQuery, you better use the functions [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) with a namespace (see documentation).

Use `.on()` to create your event and `.off()` to remove it. You can also create a global object like `g_specific_events_set = {};` to avoid duplicates:

```js
$('#alert').click(function()
{
    alert('First alert!');
});

g_specific_events_set = {};

add_specific_event = function(namespace)
{
    if (!g_specific_events_set[namespace])
    {
        $('#alert').on('click.' + namespace, function()
        {
            alert('SECOND ALERT!!!!!!');
        });
        g_specific_events_set[namespace] = true;
    }
};

remove_specific_event = function(namespace)
{
    $('#alert').off('click.' + namespace);
    g_specific_events_set[namespace] = false;
};



$('#add').click(function(){ add_specific_event('eventnumber2'); });

$('#remove').click(function(){ remove_specific_event('eventnumber2'); });
```

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin:0 5px 1px 5px;
  padding:5px 20px;
  background:#ddd;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  cursor:pointer;
}
div:active {
  margin-top:1px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="alert">
  Alert
</div>
<div id="add">
  Add event
</div>
<div id="remove">
  Remove event
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

(2019) I used `$('#'+id).removeAttr().off('click').on('click', function(){...});`

I tried `$('#'+id).off().on(...)`, but it wouldn't work to reset the onClick attribute every time it was called to be reset.

I use `.on('click',function(){...});` to stay away from having to quote block all my javascript functions.

The O.P. could now use:

`$(this).removeAttr('onclick').off('click').on('click', function(){
     displayCalendar(document.prjectFrm[ia + 'dtSubDate'],'yyyy-mm-dd', this);
});`

Where this came through for me is when my div was set with the onClick attribute set statically:

`<div onclick = '...'>`

Otherwise, if I only had a dynamically attached a listener to it, I would have used the `$('#'+id).off().on('click', function(){...});`.

Without the off('click') my onClick listeners were being appended not replaced.

Answer (score 0):

@Amirali

```
console.log(document.getElementById("SAVE_FOOTER"));
document.getElementById("SAVE_FOOTER").attribute("onclick","console.log('c')");
```

throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).attribute is not a function
```

in chrome.

Element exists and is dumped in console;