# Clone a specific image from a div to another div but change onClick and ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have code below:

```
function add_trade(elem)
{
    var myElement = $(elem);
    var img = myElement.clone();
    $('#chosen').append(img); 
}

<div id="trade">    
    <div id="chosen"></div>    
</div>          

<div id="page">         
    <div id="backpack">
        <img src="ex1.jpg" onclick="add_trade(this);">
        <img src="ex2.jpg" onclick="add_trade(this);">
    </div>      
</div>
```

This is now working and I can clone the image and place it in my "CHOSEN"-. The problem is that it copies the OnClick and I would like it replaced for another function, so they can be able to click that cloned image and remove it from the "Chosen" div. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change onclick event with jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506219/how-to-change-onclick-event-with-jquery)

Comment: Nvm, got my answer on my last try to search a good keyword.

Comment: can you post your own answer?

Comment: @andrex i chose an answer here. it basically the same on what i did, hope this helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in another way by creating element not cloning it. try this

```
    function add_trade(elem)
    {
        var myElement = $(elem),
        elemSrc = element.src;

        var img = $('<img/ >', {
              src: elemSrc,
              onclick: "your function here";
           });
        $('#chosen').append(img); 
    }
```

or solution with your approach:
before append just change attr onclick

```
function add_trade(elem)
{
    var myElement = $(elem);
    var img = myElement.clone();
    $(img).attr('onclick', 'new function');


   $('#chosen').append(img); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should drop onClick attribute and use `click()`. To make it working you have to also use `.on()` method for following for changes in both containers. So your code could look as follows:

```
<div id="trade">    
    <div id="chosen"></div>    
</div>          

<div id="page">         
    <div id="backpack">
        <img src="ex1.jpg">
        <img src="ex2.jpg">
    </div>      
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#backpack').on('click', 'img', function() {
        var myElement = $(this);
        var img = myElement.clone();
        $('#chosen').append(img);
    });

    $('#chosen').on('click', 'img', function() {
        var myElement = $(this);
        var img = myElement.remove();
    });
</script>
```