# Uncaught syntaxerror missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am getting the syntax error:

```
         Uncaught Syntax Error: missing ) after argument list
```

The data in the table appears to be showing up fine. The error appears when I hit the Delete button in the table. But I can't seem to find any issue with the code.

The flow how it works is when I hit the delete button, it opens a model window that asks if I am sure to delete the selected entry and it should delete that once I hit yes. But, when I click on the delete button, I get the pop up window but nothing happens when I hit Yes on the window. It's like to code is stuck.

---

In Main JSP:

```
       <div id="subjectArea">

       </div>

       <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content my-popup">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">  Are You Sure to Delete? </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="delete_no" onclick="">Yes</button>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
    function changeDeleteId(x) {

        $("#delete_no").attr("onclick","deleteSubjects("+x+")");
    }
```

In Sub JSP:

```
         <table width="100%" id="example" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 14px ; margin-left: 10px; text-align: center; border: 1px solid black;">
```

```
        <%--Table Headers--%>

     <th style="text-align: center">Sr.</th>
     <th style="text-align: center">Code</th>
     <th style="text-align: center">Title</th>
     <th style="text-align: center">Status</th>
     <th style="text-align: center">Actions</th>
      </tr>

     <c:forEach items="${subjects}" var="subject" varStatus="counter">
    <tr style="align-items: center">
        <td style="font-size: 14px ; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white">${counter.count}</td>
        <td style="font-size: 14px ; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white">${subject.subjectCode}</td>
        <td style="font-size: 14px ; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white">${subject.subjectName}</td>
        <td style="font-size: 14px ; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white">${subject.status}</td>
        <td style="font-size: 14px ; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white; text-align: center; margin-left: 20px">
                <%--<a style="color: green; font-weight: bold" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/subject/edit/${subject.subjectId}">Edit</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;--%>
            <a style="text-align: center" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/subject/edit/${subject.subjectId}" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o edit"></i></a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="color: red; font-weight: bold" onclick="changeDeleteId(${subject.subjectId})"><i class="fa fa-trash-o delet"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

JavaScript File:

```
             function deleteSubjects(x) {
var url = 'delete/' + x;

$.get(url, function(content) {
    $("#subjectArea").html(content);
}).fail(function() {
    alert("Something Went Wrong, Try Again!")
});
}
```

Comment: Is `subject.subjectId` a number or a string?

Comment: @RickHitchcock It's a String

Comment: That may be the issue.  Try `onclick="changeDeleteId('${subject.subjectId}')"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506219/how-to-change-onclick-event-with-jquery the comment to the accepted answer on this post talks about passing parameters like you are

Comment: I edited the code like how it was suggested there

$("#delete_no").attr("onclick","deleteSubjects('"+x+"')");

but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Any further suggestions?
@richardsong

Comment: @RickHitchcock Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with the code you pasted:

`${subject.subjectId}` is a String and it must be passed to `changeDeleteId` function as a String i.e, enclose it in quotes `changeDeleteId('${subject.subjectId}')`

`$("#delete_no").attr("onclick","deleteSubjects("+x+")");` is not the right way to bind a function to click event. Use jQuery `on()` instead. See its [API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and see the example given under "Passing data to the handler".

Finally your code will look like this:

```
function changeDeleteId(subjectId) {
   $("#delete_no").on("click", deleteSubjects, {subject: subjectId});
}

function deleteSubjects(event) {
   var url = 'delete/' + event.data.subject;
}
```

Comment: It is now taking me to the model pop up window, but when I hit Yes (Confirm to delete), I am getting this error (Screenshot - http://screencast.com/t/uX8AAcOzer)

$("#delete_no").on("click", deleteSubjects, {subject: subjectId});
This seems to be not working