# Show checkbox dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am creating a subscribe/unsubscribe checkbox, on sign up user will be subscribed by default. if user uncheck(unsubscribe) checkbox, it will ask for confirmation in `confirm()` jquery function and if it return true, ajax request will update value in database, and toggle the checkbox to run `subscribe` function on next click (without page reload).

**MY TRY**

PHP

```
<?php if($newsletter_value){ ?>
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?php echo $newsletter_value; ?>" onclick="unsubscribe();" checked>
        <span class="label-text"></span>
<? } else{ ?>
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?php echo $newsletter_value; ?>" onclick="update_newsletter(1);">
        <span class="label-text"></span>
<? } ?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function unsubscribe(){
    var c = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if(c){
            update_newsletter(0);
    }else{ $('#checkbox').prop('checked',true)}
}

function update_newsletter(newsletter){
    url = '/updateNewsletter&newsletter='+newsletter ;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function() { 
            $('#success').append("<div class='alert alert-success'><i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i> You have successfully modified your subscription <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button></div>");
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

**Problem**

On first page load, page get `newsletter_value` from controller and show respective checkbox but once user click it and at same time again click, same function will work as on first click (no toggle in functions).

Hope you understand. and thanks for help.

Comment: `confirm()` will only run if user is unsubscribing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you never exchange the `onclick` function of the checkbox.
Because as you stated the page is not reloaded. That means that the PHP code is not executed and the function stays the same (because PHP is executed on the server side).

This again means that you would have to exchange the `onclick` function in the `success` callback function of the AJAX request.

**JavaScript**

```
// ...
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function() { 
        $('#success').append("<div class='alert alert-success'><i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i> You have successfully modified your subscription <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button></div>");
        $('#checkbox').attr("onclick","update_newsletter(1);");
    },
    // ...
});
```

The way to change the `onclick` function is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506219/how-to-change-onclick-event-with-jquery#8188681).

Comment: Finally... Found the solution... Thanks Sir.